# Show hidden div after so many seconds breaks code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

setTimeout breaks code what I want to do if after a random text and image has been choosen (that works)

I have a div called quote where the random text and image goes and i want that to fade in say like in 3 seconds time ....

But it just isnt working Im a nooby so any help would be great heres the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Random</title>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "text1",
          img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
        },
        {
          text: "text2",
          img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
        },
         {
          text: "text3",
          img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
        }
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
    })();




    $('#quote').hide();

   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#quote').show();
    $('#quote').fadeIn(1000);        
  }, 3000);




  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also want the quote div to be hidden at 1st hide();
any idea's ? thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me? Of course, it never fades anything in, as it's already visible from the `show` on the line above !

Answer (score 0):

If you remove $('#quote').show(); from your setTimeout, it will fade in properly.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#quote').fadeIn(1000);        
}, 3000);
```